# AWS Parameter Must Have Values Error (value exists)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following parameter in my CloudFormation script:

```
CloudFormationURL:
  Type: String
  Description: S3 URL for nested CloudFormation templates
  Default: ""
```

This parameter covers the CloudFormation scripts in a nested folder of my deployment config.

I use it with a resource like this:

```
  CloudWatchDashboardStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "${CloudFormationURL}/cloudwatch-dashboard.cfn.yaml"
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        Environment: !Ref Environment
```

Which works fine, and has worked for months.

I needed to add another resource, so I added this:

```
BatchDNSResources:
  Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      AppName: !Ref AppName
      Environment: !Ref Environment
      DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
      DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
      AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
      SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
      S3Version: !Ref S3Version
      HostedZone: !Ref HostedZone
      VPCStackName: !FindInMap
        - EnvironmentMap
        - !Ref Environment
        - VpcStackName
      Company: !Ref Company
      CostCenter: !Ref CostCenter
      Team: !Ref Team
    TemplateURL: !Sub "${CloudFormationURL}/batch-dns.cfn.yaml"
```

CloudFormation throws this error and then fails:

> Parameters: [CloudFormationURL] must have values

Checking the changeset for the stack I can see the following value for the CloudFormationURL:

```
s3://application-shared-dev/application-name/qa/cf/nested/KShyDj205UK8mz6W_XUA5TnEF8nqPWHS
```

Checking the application predeploy logs I can see:

```
upload: deploy/cloudformation/templates/nested/batch-dns.cfn.yaml to s3://application-shared-dev/application-name/qa/cf/nested/KShyDj205UK8mz6W_XUA5TnEF8nqPWHS/batch-dns.cfn.yaml
```

And I can see the file in the S3 bucket.

If I remove `BatchDNSResource` the stack completes successfully.

What the heck am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using something to generate the CF?  Is it providing a value for `CloudFormationURL` when you create/update the stack?

Comment: Yes, @JDD. The value is in the question and I can see that it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the smallest things will get you.

I had copied the Parameters from the master CloudFormation script, including this one, into the nested script:

```
CloudFormationURL:
  Type: String
  Description: S3 URL for nested CloudFormation templates
  Default: ""
```

If you look closely, you will see that I did not pass the parameter into the nested script when calling the resource:

```
BatchDNSResources:
  Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      AppName: !Ref AppName
      Environment: !Ref Environment
      DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
      DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
      AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
      SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
      S3Version: !Ref S3Version
      HostedZone: !Ref HostedZone
      VPCStackName: !FindInMap
        - EnvironmentMap
        - !Ref Environment
        - VpcStackName
      Company: !Ref Company
      CostCenter: !Ref CostCenter
      Team: !Ref Team
    TemplateURL: !Sub "${CloudFormationURL}/batch-dns.cfn.yaml"
```

Because the CloudFormation console was saying the issue was with the `BatchDNSResources` I kept looking at the master script for the problem and missing the reference in the other script. There are two ways to solve this problem:

- Keep `CloudFormationURL` as a parameter in the nested script (if you need it for some reason) and pass the value from the master script.
- Remove the parameter from the nested script (if it is not needed)

Sometimes just asking for an extra set of eyeballs and getting a little rest will help you to find the issues. I want to leave this question/answer in place here because when I was searching for the error here and elsewhere no one ever mentioned (probably out of embarrassment) that the mistake is simply overlooking something like this. I hope this answer prompts others to check everything when they run across this type of error.